# How to handle crash during iterating over a very big list (>100 000)

Tags: jakarta-ee, architecture, iteration, batch-processing, recovery

Our system is processing more than 100 000 subscribers. On a weekly basis another external application builds special file(s) containing users' financial information with >100 000 rows. 
Our application should parse it and process every record (send sms/mms/email in our case). Of course, these operations are quite time consuming, so we're doing them asynchronously via JMS.

But first we need to put all the records to the queue. Performance test showed that it takes around 30-40 minutes or even more. 
Basically we're iterating through the whole list of 100 000 items and putting messages to the JMS queue one by one. Let's assume that on the 50,000th iteration system crashes.
If we didn't care about recovery logic, second half of the users won't receive any message.
If we simply re-launch the process, first half of the users will receive 2 identical SMS.

So we need to have here some logic that correctly recovers the iteration process with minimal performance impact.
At the moment the following solutions came to my mind:

1. Save iteration count in some persistent storage - *possibly preferable, order the same as in file*
2. Serialize the process state to some persistent storage - *bad performance?*
3. Save the whole list and update statuses- *bad performance, useless data?*
   For all of my them state data is updated to the persistent storage on each iteration.

Which one to choose?
And what is the best choice for persistent storage here (simple, fast, reliable)?

Does anybody know any solution/pattern that is usually applied in such sort of cases? Or you already encountered the same issue and can suggest your own approach?
Any help will be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: If someone's answer is useful to you, you should accept it. It will encourage them alot :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend you look at using [Spring batch](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/) which is designed to specifically address your needs. It should have no problem processing 100,000+ lines, give you the ability to restart (from the point of failure), retry, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Is your JMS provider transactional? If so you can run the whole process in one JMS transaction. The broker won't allow consumers to process any message until the transaction that sent it commits. So if your import process crashes at any time, the broker will automatically rollback all messages sent so far.

You can then restart the process from scratch.

BTW 30-40 minutes to send 100K messages to JMS queue (around 50 msgs/s)? I just did a quick test with [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/) 5.5.0 web interface and sending 100K messages takes around 1-2 minutes...

Comment: One thing to be aware of with the transaction is that you want good logging in-place during long-running processes that touch a lot of records.  It can be frustrating if the majority of records work successfully only to have the whole process rolled back because of one bad record - particularly if the records themselves aren't related.

Answer (score 0):

Because what you're doing with the records (one record doesn't care if the next or previous one was sent successfully of not) I don't think there's any need to stop if there's an error or worry about restarting from scratch; my take would be to process all the records you can and then figure out how to fix/re-process the failures.

The only thing you might want to look-out for is some sort of systemic error: there's no point trying to process 100K records if the first 50 all fail for the same reason - network failure, for example.

In the event that you want to come back and re-run failures I'd be inclined to copy-over a snapshot of data to be processed and add processing data to that (sent successful @ dd-mm-yy, hh:mm:ss, Failed,. etc).  Alternatively just log all failures into your standard logging system.